# How can you create a user orderable list box in c#?

Tags: c#, checkbox, sorting

How would I got about creating a user orderable list of check boxes in c#? The user needs to select which files out of a list they want to pass to another application and the order matters so I was looking for a method of accomplishing this using Up/Down arrow type interface on the side

Any ideas on how I should go about this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mean re-orderable rather than sortable, strictly speaking.

The listbox items property allows index-based removal and insertion.  When a user clicks the up/down arrow, simply remove the item according to the selectedindex property, and insert it back in again at +1/-1 index.

Comment: Aye thats a better way of describing it. I figured this might be the way to go about it just wanted to make sure I wasnt missing another method I wasnt aware of.